# Reference request: A co-H-space is a retract of a suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory

I would like a reference for the following result:

Let $X$ be a co-H-space. Then $X$ is a retract of a suspension $\Sigma Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proved in Theorem 1.1 of Ganea - Cogroups and Suspensions (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01404323). In particular, you can take $Z = \Omega X$.